# Angular app takes about 30 secs to load home page on PCF

Tags: angular, angular-cli, cloud-foundry

I am working an angular app(on Angular 7). The app has about 15-20 components, along with Lazy loading of modules.

Yet, the size of **main.js is about 1.27MB** after running ng build --prod.

[ng build --prod results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g761s.png)

The app is hosted on PCF. It takes about 30 seconds to load the home page whereas, it **loads in just about 2 secs in local.**

[network stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwGGJ.png)

> angular.json configuration:

```
 "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        }
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "bbc2023",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-ie-polyfills": "webpack-cli src/ie-polyfills.js -o src/generated/ie-polyfills.min.js -c webpack-polyfill.config.js",
    "postbuild": "cp -p src/generated/ie-polyfills.min.js dist/generated"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.3.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jw-angular-social-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "ng-feedback": "^1.1.8",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.3.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

> App.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,LayoutComponent,FooterComponent, HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CarouselModule,
    AppRoutesModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule ,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**NOTE:** The assets folder is about 3 MB. I am working over reducing image sizes but, I am curious to know ways to reduce main.js as well.

Please suggest if there is a way to reduce main.js size Or any other leads to improve the performance.

Comment: This is a normal bundle size for Angular 7 on the main bundle. You could try switching Angular 8 beta and using the new Ivy engine. The next version claims to have smaller bundles for the main bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress main.js and other js files from the backend

For example in node.js you can use compression module which can compress the js files and header too

compress https://github.com/expressjs/compression

And also you can use webpack analyzer if you are using webpack and other module analyzer to see whats eating upto 1.27 mb.